# Why is the for-loop choosing the wrong IF statement path?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement

So I am doing an online coding challenge and have come across this issue that has me stumped:

This is my code:

```
 static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            int noOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++)
            {
                string odds = "";
                string evens = "";

                //get the input word from console
                string word = Console.ReadLine();

                for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
                {
                    //if the string's current char is even-indexed...
                    if (word[j] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        evens += word[j];                       
                    }
                    //if the string's current char is odd-indexed...
                    else if (word[j] % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        odds += word[j];
                    }                   
                }
                //print a line with the evens + odds
                Console.WriteLine(evens + " " + odds);
            }
        }
```

Essentially, the question wants me to get the string from the console line and print the even-indexed characters (starting from index=0) on the left, followed by a space, and then the odd-indexed characters.

So when I try the word 'Hacker', I should see the line printed as "Hce akr". When I debugged it, I saw the code successfully put the letter 'H' on the left (because it is index=0, thus even), and put the letter 'a' on the right (odd index). But then when it got to the letter 'c', instead of going through the first IF path (even index), it skips it and goes to the odd index path, and places it on the right hand side?

The funny thing is when I try the word 'Rank' it works fine and prints the correct statement: "Ra nk", yet other words do not.

Its just bizarre that I'm getting different results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note : `if (someCondition) {  } else if (!someCondition) {  }` is redundant. You can remove the second `if` but keep the `else` such as `if (someCondition) {  } else {  }`

Comment: `if(j % 2 == 0) evens += word[j]; else odds += word[j];`

Comment: @Cid: Thanks, makes sense- as I was experimenting I just modified it to try different things to make it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`word[j]` is a *character* in your string; `j` is the index you want to check the evenness of.

Comment: Follow up: the reason why the original code still executes is because a `char` can be implicitly converted to an integer, which is used in the `% 2` check. Therefor, `word[j] % 2` checks if the ASCII value of the character is even or not.

Comment: @Scott Hunter: Thanks got it!

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer was downvoted

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks, good explanation, makes perfect sense now

Comment: @Cid Who knows why it was downvoted

Answer (score 3):

`if (j%2)` should provide the correct path. You're using `if( word[j] %2)` which is doing modular arithmetic on a character, not an index. Most likely using modulo on the ASCII value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Shadow Blade

Answer (score 1):

you want to check if the index is even,yet you compare `word[j] % 2 == 0` which is not an index.
what you should do:

```
if(j % 2 == 0){

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @lior

Comment: no problem! happy to help<3